# Use indexOf() function in LINQ in vb.net or C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, linq

I have a table in database that it has a column name. I have to change all Items name when I read table before showing in Grid . I must to use this LINQ Clause

```
Dim hospitalList = From l In db_Obj.VWrmz_HospitalCorrection
                       Select hospitalName = l.HOSPITAL_NAME.Substring(0,l.HOSPITAL_NAME.IndexOf("--"))
```

when i use above code i get this error message :

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

but when I remove `IndexOf()` its work correctly:

```
Dim hospitalList = From l In db_Obj.VWrmz_HospitalCorrection
                   Select hospitalName = l.HOSPITAL_NAME.Substring(10)
```

How can I do for remove something from my cells like this?

Comment: If the string "--" is not found you will return a -1.  So you then get Substring(0, -1) which causes the error message.

Comment: @jdweng - While that is a concern, it is not the source of the error.  The source of the error lies in the fact that the Entity Framework engine does not know how to translate `IndexOf` into a sql expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anonymous perhaps?

```
Dim hospitalList = From l In db_Obj.VWrmz_HospitalCorrection
                       Select New With {.hospitalName = l.HOSPITAL_NAME.Substring(0,l.HOSPITAL_NAME.IndexOf("--"))}
```

Comment: Thanks .. could you please describe me what happened exactly wit This dots ?

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, the unrecognized method is "Int32.IndexOf", the invoker of "IndexOf" method is "Int32" instead of "String", is there any possible that your HOSPITAL_NAME can be a number ??

If you cannot find the problem, you can try the regular expressions instead of "Substring" method, like this(I am using C#, so... this is the c# code, sorry for that):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("--.*");
var hospitalList = From l In db_Obj.VWrmz_HospitalCorrection
                   Select hospitalName = regex.Replace(l.HOSPITAL_NAME, "");
```

Hope this can Help

Comment: It **doesn't** say `Int32.IndexOf` but `Int32 IndexOf`. That means that _**the return value**_ of `IndexOf` is `Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# version for it.
LINQ to EF cannot translate `IndexOf` method to sql syntax. You can fetch the data and perform the operation on it later.

```
from ll in (from l in db_Obj.VWrmz_HospitalCorrection
 select hospitalName = l.HOSPITAL_NAME).ToList()
 select ll.Substring(0, ll.IndexOf("--"))
```